# ldap query on parent & child entry

Tags: ldap

My DIT:

- dc=mucompany,dc=com

  - ou=moodlegroups
  - ou=moodleusers

    - ou=Students
    - mail=student1@mail.com

      - courseCertificate=Type1
      - courseCertificate=Type2
      - courseCertificate=Type3
    - mail=student2@mail.com

      - courseCertificate=Type1
      - courseCertificate=Type2
      - courseCertificate=Type3

the mail=student1@gmail.com entry has the mail as RDN and a bunch of other attributes(cn,sn...also custom attributes) and has like childrens the CourseCertificate=value entres also containing bunch of other attributes(courseCertificateRunning=TRUE,courseCertificateEnding=20120210,...)

I need to make a query that searchs for (&(sn=Brad)(courseRunning=TRUE)) that returns  all the attributes of the parent entry and of the child entry that satisfy the filter...
Is this possible with one ldapsearch?

Any help it will means a lot to me, thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using openldap 2.4, i try to do the queres using AD Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LDAP search filters are evaluated against each individual entry, to decide if it must be returned or not. They are not evaluated against a hierarchy of entries.

Comment: Thanks Ludovic, do you have some suggestion on how to resolve my problem? is it possible doing two searches? can it be done maybe using some special ldap attribute? i realy need to find some solution for this. thanks again:)